# iOS7,the statusbar is overlapping on my view when I setNavigationBarHidden to YES

Tags: ios7, hidden, statusbar, navigationbar

In the ios7, the status bar is changed, it overlaps on my view.
I use this method to prevent this.

```
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    }
```

It works when I have a navigationbar, but I set the navigationbar hidden, the problem comes again.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your .plist file row:

`View controller-based status bar appearance = NO`